# dijit/form/checkbox initial state unchecked

Tags: javascript, checkbox, dojo, unchecked

I wrote a simple function:

```
function updatePhase6Visibility(checkbox) {
            //alert("working");
            if (checkbox.checked) {
                Phase6.show();
            }
            else {
                Phase6.hide();
            }
        }
```

The checkbox is shown in HTML using:

```
<input id="mycheck6" name="mycheck" type="checkbox" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/CheckBox" value="agreed" checked onclick="updatePhase6Visibility(this);" /> <label for="mycheck6">Phase 6</label>
```

The initial state is checked - how do I change this to unchecked?

Comment: Okay - I got the answer - simply remove the statement "Checked" from the HTML portion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove "checked"

```
Original:
<input id="mycheck6" name="mycheck" type="checkbox" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/CheckBox" value="agreed" checked onclick="updatePhase6Visibility(this);" /> <label for="mycheck6">Phase 6</label>

Updated:
<input id="mycheck6" name="mycheck" type="checkbox" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/CheckBox" value="agreed" onclick="updatePhase6Visibility(this);" /> <label for="mycheck6">Phase 6</label>
```